# Which actions are turn ending under which circumstances?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

I would be interested in a comprehensive explanation of when certain actions are turn ending. There's those where it's simple, like shooting, as they say "will end turn". Others which are obviously are not turn ending, but consume an action, like a single move, or reload. And of course free actions like opening doors that are neither turn-ending nor cost any actions.

But then there seem to be some actions, like Torque's "Tongue Pull", and Axiom's "Psych Up", which seem to be either free actions, or automatically non-turn-ending - at least I've seen gameplay of Axiom moving, using "Psych Up", and then attacking.

Is it that they are just free actions, so you could psych up and then double-move? Or do they grant an additional action if used as the second one, so move-psychup-move would be better action economy?

I've also been looking for a mod akin to XCOM2 to display action costs, but haven't found anything so far, surprisingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) All utility items (like medikits and grenades) are free actions, but you still need to have at least 1 action point remaining to use them

2) Most self-buffs like Axiom's Psych Up or Godmother's Overtime are free actions. There may be a counter-example but I can't think of one right now. Note that Adrenal Surge also allows Axiom to use Psych Up several times in a single turn to build up his rage (normally it's a free action but it still has a one-turn cooldown)

3) Actions that always end the turn (like Verge's Puppeteer or Axiom's Quake) should mention it in their tooltip. At the very least, there is a "WILL END TURN" yellow line in the description even when you're about to do it as your first action

4) Other actions cost 1 action point but do not automatically end the turn, so they can be used before or after moving for instance

5) Note that there is a weapon add-on called the Reflex Grip that transforms the act of shooting from a turn-ending action to a 1-action-cost one, meaning you can shoot and then move, or shoot twice. Similarly, auto-loaders make a certain number of reloads free every mission (1 for the basic version, and up to 3 for the superior one)

6) Some perks from leveling up or training can change an action's cost. For instance Claymore's Sticky Bomb is turn-ending when you first get it, but you can later make it only cost one action point.

7) Torque's Tongue Pull is a special case because she can *always* use Bind after pulling a target, even if she moved before doing it.

That should cover most of it.